# Delays after Windows 10 login

Tags: windows, windows-10, active-directory

I have my PC with Windows 10 configured as workstation from active directory. When the PC startups until the login screen it is done fast. After that I enter the password of my Windows account and it takes 30 minutes in order to appear the Desktop. I disabled Microsoft One drive as startup app but the problem persists.

What can I do?

Edits:

- PC Features: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1240 v6 @ 3.70GHz   3.70 GHz, 16.0 GB RAM, Win 10 64 bits, 1TB HDD

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: 30 minutes is excessively long. Are you connecting by wireless?  If so, domain connection needs to wait for wireless. Usually a couple of minutes. Otherwise your question needs much more description.

Comment: Yes, it's too long. It's connected by phisycal ethernet cable.

Comment: Please, specify what detail do you need?

Comment: Open Task Manager, Performance, and watch Network activity. Just bytes transmitted / received but it may provide a clue as to what is happening. Too much data; No data?

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Network activity: 100kbps sent 30 kbps received. These are average.

Comment: I won't be able to boot in safe mode today it will be on Monday

Comment: @user3637971 - Instead of submitting 6-7 comments you should instead [edit[ your question to include the required information to answer your question.

Comment: Do you mean the title of the post I have to change?

Comment: I restarted in safe mode by Shift + Restart. Even though, the same result happens. I think that little by little the time after login was increased. This time, it took 40min. I'm going to add as Edit the PC features.